# Scala 2.9.2 Simple string Interpolation Throwing Error

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to learn Scala and both IDE and REPL are complaining about string interpolation:

```
scala> val name = "World"
name: java.lang.String = World

scala> val message = s"Hello $name"
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but string literal found.
   val message = s"Hello $name"
                  ^
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

String interpolation is not available in 2.9.2. It was [coined in 2.10.0](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html).

Comment: Ah! Well that's crazy because brew downloads 2.9.2. I'm reading the meap of scala in action and it refers to this but yes you are correct - it does say 2.10. Also the site download space gives you 2.9.2 at the time of writing. http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads

Comment: Scala 2.10 has RC10 at time of writing if anyone is looking for it in the release candidate section of the official scala downloads: http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads

Comment: @JasonG 2.10.0 will be [officially final](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-internals/3R7xTJhcN0I/cGqzflv-JVMJ) by the end of the first week of '13

Comment: How long until the typesafe stack is on 2.10 and play 2 uses it?

Comment: @JasonG see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196926/typesafe-stack-and-scala-2-10 question

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to answer back on my own question for the osx peeps: the brew install for scala is done like this (from my confluence instance):

**Install Scala 2.10.0**
Scala has akka actors in the language so it's better to use it than the 2.9.x that brew installs.

Someone was nice enough to make a brew install for scala 2.10.0 with docs. Run in shell.

**Scala 2.10.0 with docs**

```
$brew install https://raw.github.com/gist/4525237/scala.rb --with-docs

$brew switch scala 2.10.0
```

Check you can run 'scala' after.

Comment: I wish i had seen this post a year ago.