# Typesafe stack and Scala 2.10

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, typesafe-stack

On scala's  2.10 download page ( http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads) is written:

> The Scala distribution is also available in a simple, pre-integrated
>   stack from Typesafe. Just download the Typesafe Installer from the
>   Stack Download page

But when I download it from http://typesafe.com/stack/download (current version is 2.0.2), there is still Scala version 2.9.2 (**not 2.10**).

Am I downloading typesafe stack from a wrong page, or it is simply lacking Scala 2.10? I couldn't find info whether scala 2.10 should be integrated in current version of the stack.

Answer (score 2):

The Typesafe stack includes Play2 which hasn't been released yet for Scala 2.10.

edit: Play 2.1, released in Feb 2013, [does support scala 2.10](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Highlights).

Comment: Which doesn't answer the OP's question. The 2.10 download page says the stack's available, not that it's waiting for Play2.

Comment: thanks @Stephane for reasonable note. Let's wait if someone else will know more about the issue

Answer (score 2):

The Typesafe Stack has a release model which is mostly independent of Scala’s. (See also [this comment](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-user/vPLgzdnly54/discussion) on the scala-user mailing list.)

Also note that when you are using sbt to build and package Scala applications, you’re able to specify Scala 2.10 in your `build.sbt` without any problems at all. (Unless, of course, you have dependencies which haven’t yet been updated to 2.10.)

Comment: basically, it means that current typesafe stack (2.0.2) can work with scala 2.10, however it is better to stay with default version 2.9.2 since play (part of the stack) is not ready for scala 2.10. I.e. Scala web page is more marketing than professional message. Correct?